# Unable to return string as String array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, methods, return-type

I am writing a solution for the hackerrank question, Encircular and have written a complete solution but am getting an error because I am required to return a string on a method that is string array and I can't seem to figure to how I can fix it. I searched online and tried few different things but had no luck. I have pasted my code below;

```
public class Encircular {
    static String[] find(String[] commands) {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        boolean goUp = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < commands.length(); i++) {
            switch (commands.charAt(i)) {
                case 'G' :
                    if (goUp) {
                        y++;
                    } else {
                        x++;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'L' :
                    goUp = true;
                    break;
                case 'R' :
                    goUp = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (x == 0 && y == 0) {
            return "YES";
        }
        return "NO";

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(doesCircleExist("GLGLG"));
        System.out.println(doesCircleExist("GRGL"));
    }
```

The error I am getting is:

```
      location: variable commands of type String[]
Solution.java:37: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to String[]
            return "YES";
                   ^
Solution.java:39: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to String[]
        return "NO";
```

I tried storing the string as array and then returning the array like so, but had no luck;

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("YES");
list.add("NO");


 if (x == 0 && y == 0) {
        return list.get[0];
    }
    return list.get[1];
```

Also, I am getting this error, I am not sure what it means:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-sun/bin/javac -encoding UTF-8  -classpath ':*:/usr/share/java/*' Solution.java 1> compile.err 2>&1
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to return multiple strings at once? Because you declare that you do (`String[]`), but in fact you return a single string.

Comment: If you want to return an array, return one: `return new String[]{"YES"};`. But it looks like you're actually trying to return a `String`, or even just a `boolean`.

Answer (score 2):

You have the return type of your method as an array of strings. If you change it to just

```
static String find(String[] commands)
```

Then it will let you return a single string

EDIT:

Since you can't change the method deceleration you can simply do what @raluca suggested and create two different arrays. One contains only yes and one contains only no and return one of those.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, the hacker rank method is like this; static String[] find(String[] commands), which I cannot change.

Comment: So the requirements are that you can't change the declaration of the method?

Comment: then you need to change your response string arrays: new String[] {  
"YES"} and new String[] {  "NO"}

Comment: @GBlodgett Yes, I can't change that